# Setting up AWS CloudWatch Alarms to alert via SNS if in INSUFFICIENT_DATA state

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I've been completely unable to get a clear, straight answer about undertaking this, and am at a point where there doesn't seem to be one doc page or forum post to refer to.

Currently, I've got CloudWatch alarms set in place to monitor a variety of variables to alert on breach for, through SNS to Slack. One thing that I'm looking to do after the fact, is to make sure that any alarms in the INSUFFICIENT_DATA status get their own alerts sent to Slack, as well. I assumed setting up composite alarms would lead me down the right path, but it doesn't actually look like this method enables me to send out alerts on that status. Getting the cloudwatch agents out to the instances, along with the configs, was done via chef recipe.

My infrastructure is on the larger side, and there are at least five metrics that are being monitored, which leaves me with 1370+ alarms. Getting these alarms to alert on INSUFFICIENT_DATA statuses needs to (or ideally) be done in one large swathe, or in large, individual batches. I'm not finding a single, rational way to do this, either. Scripting this out could be the answer, sure, but I'm unsure how to tailor the script to grab each and every alarm name and add this specific type of alert variable to them.

If anyone has any idea about how to proceed, I'd be immensely grateful. This is big task blocker right now, so I'm willing to work out a solution one phase at a time. Thanks very much!!